# Online tool for ranking students by comparing pairs

Tags: web-apps, survey

As a teacher, I face the recurring problem of having students identify the weakest members of their project group (consisting of 4 to 10 members).

One of the students pitched the idea of having group members rank themselves by making them go through a series of successive questions with binary responses: "Is student A or B a better contributor to the project?" for several student-student combinations.

Does anyone know of an easy-to-use online tool that allows me to enter student's names and then have them 'vote' in the manner specified above? The output would have to be a sorted list (preferably with some scores attached if possible).